# Error: stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Am sending photo to the server side from the front-end to the back-end using ng-file-upload here is my code:

View:

```
<form name="photoForm" ng-submit="uploadPicture(files)">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Add Caption" ng-model="caption">
    <input type="button" name="files" value="Upload picture" ngf-select ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-pattern="'image/*'">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default submitButton" ng-disabled="!photoForm.$valid">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="f in files" style="font:smaller">
        {{f.name}}{{f.$errorParam}}
      </li>
    </ul> </form
```

Controller:

```
// Upload Image
$scope.uploadPicture = function(files){

  if (files && files.length) {
      $scope.uploadFiles(files);
  }
};

$scope.uploadFiles = function(files){
   Upload.upload({
    url: '/api/posts/photo',
    method: 'POST',
    file: files
  }).then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.result = response.data;
        });
    }, function (response) {
        if (response.status > 0) {
            $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
        }
    });
};
```

Route:

```
var  multipart = require('connect-multiparty'),
     multipartMiddleware = multipart();

app.route('/api/posts/photo')
      .post(multipartMiddleware, photos.create);
```

Server:

```
exports.create = function(req, res){

  console.log(req.body, req.files);
};
```

when ever I console.log(req.files), without the multipartMiddleware am able to see the file I uploaded, but once I add the multipartMiddleware the error message kept showing.

Comment: I am finding the solution  for the same. Reference: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#usage